# Session multi-dimensional array error

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am having a problem with a session multi-dimensional array I am trying to add values to. I am told that I should state the array "before" I start adding values, but when I do that the array is treated like a normal array without being a session. Thus, that will not work for my case. At the same time, the code error is ruining my code.  I have no idea how I can solve this problem.

Here are the code lines which are causing the error message

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array

(Of course I have more code than this, these are just the lines that affect the issue):

PHP:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['part_number']); $i++) {
$_SESSION['qty'][$i] = $_POST['qty'][$i];
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="qty[0]" size="2" />
```

Comment: `['qty']` needs to be an array before you set values to it

Comment: What is `$_SESSION['qty']`?  Try: `var_dump($_SESSION['qty']);`.

Comment: @RUJordan, Like I said, then the array is treated as a regular array instead of a Session, correct?

Comment: Check for existence of $_SESSION['qty'] and if exists check it's type with is_array() ... if it's an array you should be able to alter it, if not it must not be set, so create a new array.

Comment: Are you calling session_start? If you don't start it manually and it's not started automatically, then $_SESSION won't be magic.

Comment: @Tigerman55 `$_SESSION` is an array, it's just a superglobal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, either `$_SESSION['qty']` or `$_POST['qty']` is not an array. Try this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['qty']) || !is_array($_SESSION['qty'])) $_SESSION['qty'] = array();
if(!is_array($_POST['qty'])) throw new Exception('Error: $_POST[\'qty\'] is not an array!');
for($i=0; $i < count($_POST['part_number']); $i++) {
    if(!isset($_POST['qty'][$i])) continue;
    $_SESSION['qty'][$i] = $_POST['qty'][$i];
}
```

Comment: Check your quotes in the exception

Comment: Yes, I had to escape the single quotes. However, other than that this worked excellent! Thank you.

Comment: @RUJordan Oops, you're right, I forgot to escape the quotes. Fixed now.